# What is a List`1 object?

Tags: powershell, generics, types

A System.IO.FileInfo has a Target member.

Using `Get-Item -Path * -Include 't.txt' | Get-Member` shows it to have a `Target` member that is a `CodeProperty`.

Using `GetType()` shows it to be a `` List`1 ``

```
C:>Get-Item -Path * -Include 't.txt' | ForEach-Object { $_.Target.GetType() }

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     List`1                                   System.Object

C:>Get-Item -Path * -Include 't.txt' | % { $_.Target.GetType() | % { $_.FullName } }
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]
```

Comment: It's a [generic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/), a type-safe way to store objects without hard-coding types in advance.

Comment: Also see: .net generics, ildasm, anonymous methods/lambdas/delegates, function/data representations in c# debugger (call stack/locals) for example, etc.

Comment: As an aside: strictly speaking, the `.Target` property is defined in terms of an _interface_, namely (using C# notation) `IEnumerable<string>` (verify with `([System.IO.FileInfo]::new('/') | Get-Member Target).Definition`). The _implementing type_ is `List<string>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[vonPryz](https://stackoverflow.com/users/503046/vonpryz) has provided the crucial pointer in a comment: `` List`1 `` is **.NET's representation of a [generic type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/generics/) named `List` with arity (`` ` ``) `1`, i.e., a generic type with 1 type parameter**.

(The use of `` ` `` in this context is unrelated to PowerShell's use of `` ` `` as the escape character).

In your case, `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] `` indicates that **the generic type was *closed* (instantiated) with type `System.String`**.

Leaving the assembly qualification aside (`mscorlib, Version = ...`), the **equivalent PowerShell representation is `` System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[string]] ``**, which can be simplified in two ways, however:

- The arity indicator, `` `1 ``, can be omitted, given that the arity is implied by the type argument in `[...]`, `[string]`.
- Given that there's only *1* type parameter, you can omit the outer `[...]` around the type argument list.

Therefore, you can use just `System.Collections.Generic.List[string]`, or, expressed as a PowerShell *type literal* (`[...]`), `[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]`

---

**Optional reading: Shortening type names and literals in PowerShell:**

`[System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]` is a bit unwieldy, and there are two ways to shorten it:

- **PowerShell allows you omit the `System.` part of the namespace for any type**, so `[Collections.Generic.List[string]]` works too.
- PowerShell **v5+** offers the **`using namespace` statement**, analog to C#'s `using` statement:

  ```
    # Note:
    #  * `using namespace` must be at the *start* of the script (potentially
    #    preceded by other `using` statements and comments only)
    #  * The 'System.' part of a namespace must *not* be omitted.
    using namespace System.Collections.Generic

    [List[string]] # short for: [System.Collections.Generic.List[string]]
  ```

Additionally, PowerShell has **built-in *type accelerators*** for certain often-used types, which are single-component names that refer to specific types without needing to specify their namespace of origin; e.g., `[xml]` is a type accelerator for `[System.Xml.XmlDocument]`.

[This TechNet blog post](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/heyscriptingguy/2013/07/08/use-powershell-to-find-powershell-type-accelerators/) shows that you can use the following command to **list all built-in type accelerators**:

```
[psobject].Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")::
  get.GetEnumerator() | Sort-Object Key
```

As [TheIncorrigible1](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8188846/theincorrigible1) points out, you can even **define your own type accelerators with the `::Add()` method**; e.g., the following command defines `[cmdinfo]` as an accelerator for type `[System.Management.Automation.CommandInfo]`:

```
[psobject].Assembly.GetType("System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators")::
      Add('cmdinfo', [System.Management.Automation.CommandInfo])
```

The new accelerator will be available *session-globally* (but only for the current session), even if the call is made from a child scope.

That said, **there's a good reason *not* to do this**:

- `System.Management.Automation.TypeAccelerators` is *not a public type*, so it isn't part of PowerShell's public API, and therefore not guaranteed to be there (in its present form) in the future.
- Therefore, **the `using namespace` approach is preferable**.