# What is the difference between char[] and char?

Tags: powershell

If I use the `[char]` datatype, it requires the value to be one character, e.x.

```
[char]"a"
a
```

Since if I use it with more than one character it will give me an error:

```
[char]"ab"
Cannot convert value "ab" to type "System.Char". Error: "String must be exactly one
character long."
At line:1 char:1
+ [char]"ab"
+ ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InvalidCastParseTargetInvocation
```

However if I use

```
[char[]]"ab"
```

I get the output

```
a
b
```

If I compare `Get-Member` on both, I get no result:

```
PS C:\Users\nijoh> Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $([char] | gm) -DifferenceObject $([char[]] | gm) -PassThru
PS C:\Users\nijoh>
```

But I can see that they are two distinct types since they show up differently:

```
PS C:\Users\nijoh> ([char[]]"a").GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Char[]                                   System.Array


PS C:\Users\nijoh> ([char]"a").GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     Char                                     System.ValueType
```

So what is the difference between the `[char]` and `[char[]]` datatypes in Powershell?

Comment: `[char]` is an object of type char. `[char[]]` is an object of type array that contains char types.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In PowerShell, a type name enclosed in `[...]` is a *type literal*, i.e. an object that represents the .NET type named.

Independently of that, *inside* `[...]`, `[]` *immediately after a type name* represents an *array* containing elements of that type; for an overview of the notation used inside `[...]`, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57246523/45375).

Therefore:

- **`[char]` refers to type `System.Char`** (the `System.` prefix is generally *optional* in PowerShell; additionally - as is the case here - PowerShell has a fixed set of *type accelerators* that allow you to use simple names for types located in *any* namespace - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54962710/45375)).

  - To get a given type literal's full (namespace-qualified) .NET type name, use `[...].FullName`; e.g., `[char].FullName` yields [`System.Char`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Char)
- **`[char[]]` refers to an *array* type whose *elements* are of type `char`** ( `System.Char`); `[char[]].FullName` yields `System.Char[]`.

---

> Since if I use it with more than one character it will give me an error (`[char]"ab"`)

PowerShell has no `[char]` literals, only *string* (`[string]`) literals. When you cast a *string* to `[char]` - which represents a *single* character - only a *single-character* string is accepted; e.g. `[char] 'a'` works, but `[char] 'ab'` or `[char] "ab"` doesn't.

> However if I use `[char[]]"ab"` ...

Casting a string to an *array* of characters returns a character array comprised of the string's individual characters.

In other words: `[char[]] "ab"` is equivalent to `"ab".ToCharArray()`.

> If I compare `Get-Member` on both, I get no result:

The reason is that **`Get-Member` operates on the *types* of the input objects**, and if the input objects are *type literals* - such as `[char]` and `[char[]]` - *their* type is examined, which is `System.RuntimeType`, a non-public PowerShell type that derives from [`System.Reflection.TypeInfo`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Reflection.TypeInfo), which describes a .NET *type*.

In other words: **all *type literals* piped to `Get-Member` will result in the *same* output, irrespective of what specific type they refer to**, because it is the one and only type-*describing* type whose members are being reported.

Therefore, using `Compare-Object` on `Get-Member` calls with different type literals predictably produces *no* output, because the `Get-Member` calls result in the same output<sup>[1]</sup>. (Not producing output is `Compare-Object`'s way of indicating that no differences were detected.)

---

<sup>[1] `Get-Member` outputs an array of [`Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MemberDefinition`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.MemberDefinition) instances, one for each member of the input object's *type*. In the absence of a `-Property` argument passed to `Compare-Object`, these instances are compared *as a whole*, by their `.ToString()` value, which yields a meaningful representation of each member.</sup>